# How to clearly indicate that certain attributes cannot be modified on a edit operation

Tags: user-interface, usability

We have a requirement that shouldn't allow a user to modify certain fields on a edit. We currently disable such fields (e.g. a drop-down or a date field or a text field). How do applications provide a visual feeling that a field is not modifiable, is there a elegant way that is being done by applications, than the above approach?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that a standard way is to 'gray it out' with gray text / font color

Another option is to use input fields for changable items and just plain HTML when it's read only.

The one hard thing might be the select boxes.  If they present a list of values and you can change which one is selected you have a control that now feels like an edit.  For this issue I would consider either really not using a select box and actually listing out all the options directly with the chosen one being bolded in some way, or I would use a select box and put a literal note, something like "this is read-only, selecting a different value will not change the current setting".